# Apache Beam - Can someone show how to truncate table table using JdbcIO?

Tags: apache-beam

Can someone show me how to truncate table using JdbcIO ? I been searching for few days but no luck.

Comment: What is a point to do that with `JdbcIO` and not just with Java jdbc client? `JdbcIO` for Beam is supposed to be used in a distributed way .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.